# Wordpress Custom post login page

Tags: wordpress, authentication, themes

> Kindly refer some plugin for wordpress post login. 
>   I have 3 page website site home, about and work normal and work secure, i want to show the work secure page if the user login with there email / just dummy id which i can generate.
>   Unable to find the plugin for this login module.
>   Custom menu with custom page

[image]

Using this script i am able to create menu but not able to redirect separate page

function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

```
$args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
```

} else {

```
$args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
```

}

```
return $args;
```

}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );

Answer (score 0):

If user is logged, he is redirect in 'about us' page

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    $redirect_to = get_page_link(ID_PAGE_ABOUT_US);
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This code is redirect to my admin wp page.
How does above code will work ? I need to create button for login ?
I'm little confuse about this coding. 
Will you be suggest some plugin for user. So that i can give them access to see my secure web page.